# How to lock object permanentely to (Z) axis?

Tags: modeling, transforms, axis

i hope somebody can help me out,

as you can see in the video (https://streamable.com/eiqs80). The object got moved a few times and always stays on the Z axis. On the screencast you can see she neither clicked Z or MMB after clicking G.

How can i lock an object permanentely to an axis?

Please let me know, im getting crazy here ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Chris' answer actually does answer the question, it seems what you want is to automatically constrain the translation operator to the Z axis.

It's not possible to "permanently" constrain translations of an object both in object mode and edit mode to a given axis, but you can change the <kbd>G</kbd> keymap entry to always be constrained to an axis by default.

Go to Edit > Preferences > Keymap and search for `translate` in the search bar. Navigate to the 3D View panel and expand the one with a Keyboard entry. Then just click on the Z Constraint axis and save the preferences.

[image]

Comment: +1 that's new to me too....although it makes no sense to me - but very interesting

Comment: @Chris I guess you can remap it to another keyboard entry or a mouse button, if you have a very specific workflow where you translate along one axis 90% of the time it saves you having to middle click or press the axis letter. Gotta think about your finger joints ! :)

Comment: @Gorgious Thats was exactly what i was looking for thanks to you and to @Chris!

Since its all quite new to me, i most probably couldnt phrase the question right!

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

She might have clicked that locks here before:

[image]

Then the object will move only on z axis.

OR....

she might have an object constraint like this:

[image]